# How can I force the JAXB/Moxy to follow the order during unmarshalling?

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink, unmarshalling, moxy

I am quite new to `JAXB/Moxy` and trying to implement `Marshalling and Unmarshalling`. After a lot of searches and reading articles, I am aware that we can use `proporder` so marshaling follows the order but how can I ensure that `unmarshalling` follows the order?

Following is the `Customer` POJO I have:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Customer")
@XmlType(name = "Customer", propOrder = {"name", "others"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Customer {

  private String name;

  @XmlPath(".")
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(TestAdapter.class)
  @JsonSerialize(using = CustomExtensionsSerializer.class)
  private Map<String, Object> others = new HashMap<>();

  @JsonAnySetter
  public void setOthers(String key, Object value) {
    others.put(key, value);
  }

  public Customer xmlSupport() {
    return this;
  }
}
```

While `unmarshalling` the `XML` file all the `XML Node and data` automatically populated into the `Map<String,Object> others` field due to which when I try to create `JSON` from the `unmarshaled` I get all the fields within the `others`:

```
{
  "name" : "",
  "others" : {
    "name" : "MY",
    "google:sub" : "bye"
  }
}
```

To avoid this I want to make sure that my `unmarshaller` follows the order and populated the field `name` first then it populates all unmatching fields to my `Map<String, Object>`.

Please note: `@XmlPath(".")` is required for me during the `marshaling` as I would like to skip the `others` node but retaining the values within it. so I cannot remove this.

Any help or inputs will be really appreciated.